# collatz conjecture to print the number of objects and the sequence using class

Tags: c++, sequence, collatz

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    class ulam
    {
        int num;
        double prod;
        int cot;
    public:
        ulam(){cot=0;}
        ulam(int x)
        {
            num=x;
        }

        void process()
        {
          for(int i=0;num==1;i++)
          {
            cout<<num<<endl;
            if((num%2) == 0)
            {
              prod=num/2;
            }
            else
            {
              prod=(3*num)+1;
            }
            num=prod;
            cot++;
          }
        }
        void display()
        {
            cout<<"the number of steps required is: "<<cot;
        }
    };
    int main()
    {
        int n;
        cout<<"enter the number"<<endl;
        cin>>n;
        ulam obj(n);
        obj.process();
        obj.display();
    }
```

when i write this code the cot value comes as a garbage value i think. i cant figure out where i went wrong. i used class because i feel it is more discriptive . but the main aim behind this program is to find the number of steps it is required for a number to reach one and to print the whole sequence of numbers. for thos who dont know about the collatz conjecture https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture

Comment: `ulam(int x)` never sets `cot`

Comment: you can set a initial value during declaration, `int cot = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

Your condition of the for loop inside process function is wrong. it should be `num!=1`. You need to initialize `cot` too. You don't need `prod` actually.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class ulam
{
    int num;
    int cot;
public:
    ulam()
    {
        cot=0;
    }
    ulam(int x)
    {
        cot=0;
        num=x;
    }

    void process()
    {
      for(int i=0;num!=1;i++)
      {
        cout<<num<<endl;
        if((num%2) == 0)
        {
          num=num/2;
        }
        else
        {
          num=(3*num)+1;
        }
        cot++;
      }
    }
    void display()
    {
        cout<<"the number of steps required is: "<<cot;
    }
};
int main()
{
    int n;

    cout<<"enter the number"<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    ulam obj(n);
    obj.process();
    obj.display();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### First Problem

In the constructor where you initialize when an integer is passed, you **ALSO** have to initialize `cot` like this:

```
ulam(int x)
{
    cot = 0;
    num = x;
}
```

Better yet, since cot is always going to be `0` at construction, just set `cot` to `0` as a private variable like this:

```
class ulam
{
   int num;
   double prod;
   int cot = 0;
public:
  //....
};
```

This means that you could still have a default constructor that will do nothing, and the one that takes an integer won't require cot to be set to `0`.

### Second Problem

Your second problem is that the loop condition is wrong. It should be `num != 1`, not `num == 1`. `num == 1` would be the loop would never run unless 1 was passed in `cin`.